# STI and Polymorphic Association possible in rails 4? Not working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, sti

I'm somewhat of a newbie with ruby on rails and went off of [samurails.com single table inheritance with rails 4 tutorial](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) to add different comment types. This worked great but the problem I'm running into is when I try to use polymorphic associations to get comments and the specific type to function under other models such as project and challenge. A regular comment works, but the specific types do not.

I haven't seen anything that clearly says how to make this work or another option of going about it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_merit
  acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :commenttype
  belongs_to :project

  def self.types
    %w(Question Idea Problem)
  end

  def commentable_type=(sType)
    super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end

  scope :questions, -> {where(type: 'Question')}
  scope :ideas, -> {where(type: 'Idea')}
  scope :problems, -> {where(type: 'Problem')}
end

class Question < Comment

end

class Idea < Comment

end

class Problem < Comment

end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :class_name => "Comment"
  has_many :questions, :as => :commentable, :class_name => "Question"
  has_many :ideas, :as => :commentable, :class_name => "Idea"
  has_many :problems, :as => :commentable, :class_name => "Problem"

  delegate :questions, :ideas, :problems, to: :comments

end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_type
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @comments = type_class.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @comment = type_class.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create 
      @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user
      if @comment.save
        redirect_to :back, notice: "#{type} was successfully added."
      else
        render action: 'new'
      end
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "#{type} was successfully updated."
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @comment = @commentable.comments.where(comment_user: current_user).first
    @commentable.comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was deleted." }
      format.js
  end
end

private

def set_comment
  @comment = type_class.find(params[:id])
end

def set_type
  @type = type
end

def type
  Comment.types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : "Comment"
end

def type_class
  type.constantize
end

def set_commentable
  @commentable = find_commentable
end

# add more commentable models here
def find_commentable
  if params[:challenge_id]
    Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
  else
  end
end

def find_commentable
  if params[:project_id]
    Project.find(params[:project_id])
  else
  end
end


  def comment_params 
    params.require(type.underscore.to_sym).permit(:body, :type, :user_id, :commentable_id, :commentable_type, :commentable, :comment_type) 
  end

end

module CommentsHelper

  def sti_comment_path(type = "comment", comment = nil, action = nil)
    send "#{format_sti(action, type, comment)}_path", comment
  end

  def format_sti(action, type, comment)
    action || comment ? "#{format_action(action)}#{type.underscore}" : "#{type.underscore.pluralize}"
  end

  def format_action(action)
    action ? "#{action}_" : ""
  end

end

<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "What's on your mind?" %>

<%= f.label :type %><br>
<%= f.select :type, Comment.types.map {|r| [r.humanize, r.camelcase]}, {}, disabled: @type != "Comment" %> 

    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn pull-right" %>
```